# How to handle menu template effectively in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I am looking for a better way to handle my template.
Right now, my template looks something like this:

view/template.php

```
$this->load->view('includes/menu', $menu);  
$this->load->view('includes/content', $main_content);
```

The menu in my template uses several variables from database.

My controller looks something like this:

```
function show_pageA() {
    /*                                           */
    /*                                           */
    /*                                           */
    /*                                           */
    /*                                           */
    /* 10 lines menu related codes here          */
    /* mainly to get variables from databas      */
    /*                                           */
    /*                                           */
    /*                                           */
    /*                                           */

    $data['menu'] = array of variables pulled from previous line        
    $data['main_content'] = 'pageA';                
    $this->load->view('template',$data);
}

function show_pageB() {
    /*                                           */
    /*                                           */
    /*                                           */
    /*                                           */
    /*                                           */
    /* 10 lines menu related codes here          */
    /* mainly to get variables from databas      */
    /*                                           */
    /*                                           */
    /*                                           */
    /*                                           */

    $data['menu'] = array of variables pulled from previous line        
    $data['main_content'] = 'pageB';                
    $this->load->view('template',$data);
}
```

As you can see, each page function has 10 lines of menu related code, and this seems redundant to me.

Can anyone suggest me a better way of doing this while practicing MVC?

Thanks,

Comment: When you say "menu" are you referring to a navigation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 different things I would do to remedy this situation.

1. I would wrap these 10 lines of code into a [Model](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html), because like you have said, it interacts with the database.  Maybe create a `Menu_model` that has a `get()` function that returns the array of items you need loaded into your views.  Then calling it in each controller would be as simple as

   ```
   $data['menu'] = $this->menu_model->get();  //assuming you autoload this model
   ```
2. But lets not stop their as this is still a repeated line of code in ***EVERY*** controller function.  Lets do this in the Controller's constructor so that these options are loaded globally in all views we produce.

*assuming you're php5'd*

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    //get menu data
    $global_data['menu'] = $this->menu_model->get();

    //load into all views loaded by this controller
    $this->load->vars($global_data);
}
```

Then, your controller functions would look like this.

```
function show_pageA() {       
    $data['main_content'] = 'pageA';                
    $this->load->view('template',$data);
}
```

*(Also, if this 'menu' logic spans multiple controllers, I would recommend rolling a custom `MY_Controller.php` that includes this logic so you again, are not repeating yourself in every controller constructor)*

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using Codeigniter views when it comes to templating and partials, you should look into using a templating library. There are quite a few around you might find useful and they all mostly handle breadcrumb navigation, view partials and other awesome things you're wanting to do.

I use Phil Sturgeon's template library in my Codeigniter projects because it's light and just works: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-template

Colin Williams template library is another popular templating library:http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/

And a few people seem to love using Ocular template library: https://github.com/lonnieezell/Ocular-Template-Library